# Team Signup Credit Card Month Expiration

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I cannot sign up for Stack Overflow Teams because the signup form doesn't show month expirations prior to May (I assume because the current month is May).

**Update:**
You have to set the year first to get the other months. It makes total sense now, but I have to admit it stumped me. If it were me, I would probably show all months and then just validate afterwards if they do pick the current year.

[image: No months before May]

Comment: Do you mean _I cannot sign up with an expired credit card_? If you change the year, other months will likely become available.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth probably true, but given the way the drop downs are presented the workflow would be assumed as set month then year.

Comment: Yup, it's not very good UI. But if that's the point of the question, it's asked a bit weirdly

Comment: Ohhh, yeah, I'm an idiot.

Comment: Yeah, the UI for this is weird. I've dropped it into one of our internal chatrooms.

Comment: Edited to note what you have to do to get it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was figured out: this worked but was a little funny for most people - we've changed it so you can get all the months without having to change the year first.